# How to set code files to be compiled on Bluemix other than sample?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, devops

I'm really new to Bluemix and I didn't find any other similar questions here on StackOverflow.
I created my first Bluemix application, tried the `/api/hello` servlet and it worked.
I added my code using DevOps online code editing in the same package `(com.ibm.cloudoe.samples)`, or in others; but it doesn't work, it seems like Bluemix can't see where my code is, and only looks for `HelloResource.java`, which is the default code for the project.
How can I set my code files to be compiled?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

The HelloResource.java is configured in web.xml in the starter code, so you can't put your code where you want. The deploy makes a .war file that, then, is started. You can configure all information about build and deploy in manifest.yml and map your servlet in web.xml.

I suggest you to download starter code and take a look at "web.xml" and "manyfest.yml" file. Then, you can edit it locally (with your favourite IDE\editor) and push it using CloudFoundry command line (https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/install_cli.html). You can find documentation on Liberty for Java here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#liberty

Comment: Thank you Crescenzo, I looked at those files, but I can't see no direct link to "HelloResource".. I am not sure how I can add my code to that! I must use CLI, or I can use only DevOps? Thank you.

Comment: You can't see no direct link to "HelloResource" cause in web.xml there is a generic mapping: " <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern> " for servlets. The real url is putted in HelloResource.java throught the annotation @Path("/hello"). So you you can Access to servlet with this url: http://youappname.mybluemix.net/api/hello

Comment: In fact, i tried to add the annotation @path into my .java file too, but it didn't work.. I think I'll read the official quick start tutorial. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using DevOps Services, you should at first be sure that after editing the code you commit it. After the commit you should push it to Bluemix. To do this you should use the *Git Repository* panel of the DevOps Services Web IDE (you can find it on the left in the *Edit Code* view). Please take a look at [DevOps Services - Git Docs](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/git/). There you can also configure your build mechanism using the *Build & Deploy* button. Please take a look at [DevOps Services - Build and deploy Docs](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/deploy/)